# Build Issues using XCode 4.1 & iOS 4.3 on Mac OS X Lion(10.7)

Tags: build, xcode4, compiler-errors, ios4, osx-lion

I'm facing build issues for my iPhone application for the above configuration. My application use to run perfectly fine 
on Snow Leapord Xcode 3.2.5 and SDK 4.2.

Here are the errors im getting .

1)

DataModelCompile /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/LRWLogs.mom LRWLogs.xcdatamodeld/LRWLogs.xcdatamodel
    cd "/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone"
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/usr/bin/momc -XD_MOMC_SDKROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -XD_MOMC_IOS_TARGET_VERSION=4.0 -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphonesimulator -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphoneos -XD_MOMC_TARGET_VERSION=10.6 "/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone/LRWLogs.xcdatamodeld/LRWLogs.xcdatamodel" /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/LRWLogs.mom

### Command /Developer/usr/bin/momc failed with exit code 1

2)

Ld /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/Pinecone normal i386
    cd "/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone/GData/bin/Debug-iphonesimulator" -L../../SDK/qo/lib -L../../SDK/openssl-fips-1.2.3 -L/Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L../../SDK/qo/lib "-L/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone" "-L/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone/../../SDK/sqlcipher/lib" "-L/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone/../../SDK/openssl-fips-1.2.3/lib" -F/Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Intermediates/Pinecone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.build/Objects-normal/i386/Pinecone.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lGDataTouchStaticLib -lxml2 -all_load -ObjC -lsqlcipher /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcrypto.a /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libsqlcipher.a /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libiOSCommon.a /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libZipArchive.a -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -lz -framework QuartzCore -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreText -framework GameKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lxml2 -framework CoreTelephony -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework EventKit -lsqlite3 -o /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/Pinecone

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

---

3)

GenerateDSYMFile /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app.dSYM /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/Pinecone
    cd "/Users/roopeshm/Projects/PineCone/Latest PineCone 07282011/Pinecone/iphone"
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/Pinecone -o /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app.dSYM

error: unable to open executable '/Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/Pinecone'

---

I guess im getting this error (3) because of the first 2 errors. I have been struck with this errors for the past 2 days and not proceeding further.
It would be a great help if someone throws some light on how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the complete answer it looks like the original error is due to your Core Data model. Check to see if you have a data model with the extension of ".xcdatamodel" instead of ".xcdatamodeld" for versions.

It looks like it is not able to compile your Core Data model until you convert the file.

Good luck!

Comment: I was able to fix the first Error. I had to delete the .xcdatamodel file for the corresponding file.

But I still have the second ERROR. The G++ compiler throwing me this error.


Ld /Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-~/Users/roopeshm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pinecone-blpusijjphhmenddbrefttvxgsyl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pinecone.app/Pinecone

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1